# What is the difference between a WixExtension and a CustomAction in Wix?

Tags: c#, wix

I am attempting to write something that can add to my Wix installer that automates connecting to a server and verifying we have access.  I know how to do this with C# code but am confused as to how to integrate this with Wix.

I think I need either a WixExtension or a CustomAction.  Can somebody please point me in the right direciton?  What is the difference/relationship between these concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you create a C++/C# DLL and build it to Windows Installer standards.  You then author it into your MSI  Binary / CustomAction / InstallExecuteSequence (or similar) tables.  You now have a custom action.

A well defined custom action should follow a number of best practices including being data driven.  Instead of hard coding values into code they should be abstracted out into custom tables.  The custom action in immeadiate contenxt should query these tables, make evaluations and serialize an instruction set passed to the deferred context that then has perms to do the work.   This is how MSI works in you have actions like  ServiceInstall and a table called ServiceInstall.  Make sense?

Ok, now an extension is a way of making all of this more elegant.  You create an XSD to describe these relationships and a DLL to extend the compiler.   Now instead of having to write all this WXS you add a reference to the DLL, add the XSD namespace and write a few elements and let the compiler take care of the details.

Odds are you just need a custom action.  But if you ever write something really powerful, reusable and want to share with the world.... make an extension.